# phpmyadmin 4.6.3 setup page shows blank page

Tags: phpmyadmin

I installed (fresh)  Linux Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS and install webmin, and php and mysql server... When I installed phpmyadmin or upload it via ftp to root of my website.. the setup page shows blank/ only phpmyadmin logo.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlUaW.jpg). 
I upload phpmyadmin and renamed the config.sample.php.inc to config.inc.php.

Comment: why did you uploaded phpmyadmin? you can easily install by running `sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin`.

Comment: because after installing, i couldn't access phpmyadmin via  ip/phpmyadmin.. i get an error "page does not exist"..

Comment: what's your server? apache or nginx?

Comment: Any hints in the webserver error log?

Comment: now it's work.. php was not working correct..

Answer (score 0):

Install phpmyadmin first by running:

```
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

Then, if you are using Apache:

Open apache.conf file using your favorite editor.

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Then add the following line in it:

```
Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
```

Restart Apache by running following:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

And if you are using nginx, you will need to create a symbolic link:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin/ /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Comment: Thank you.. now i can access phpmyadmin, but i get this errors [link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/YwnRR.jpg)

Comment: thank you.. now it's works fine.. i had some php server error.